# Control when to execute a windows batch command in hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I currently use Hudson CI and would like to know if it's possible to conditionally execute a build step depending on if there are changes in the build or not.  We currently have an automatic build process that is scheduled to run daily, and the batch command automatically tags each build.  However, I don't need it to tag a build if there are no changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a periodic build that only runs if there has been an SCM change you can switch from a periodic build trigger to a "Poll SCM" trigger, with the SCM polling schedule set to the same cron pattern as your existing build.